# How do I stop wait cursor when using setInterval

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following page that calls a javascript function (in this case, *jsDoSomething*) every 2 seconds:

```
<html>
   <head>..stuff...</head>
   <body onload="jsBodyOnload()">
      ...body...

      <script>
         function jsBodyOnload() {
            setInterval(jsDoSomething,2000);
         }
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Everything works fine, however for the duration setInterval runs the function *jsDoSomething*, the cursor changes to the wait cursor, then back to the default when done. How can I stop the cursor from changing everything this function runs? I would like to keep the cursor the same (being the default cursor) at all times on the page.

Thanks.

Comment: And what `jsDoSomething` does?

Comment: It isn't the fact that you are using `setInterval()` that the cursor changes but must be what `jsDoSomething` is doing, probably something quite intensive. Can you [edit] to post the `jsDoSomething` code, or at least explain what it does?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it is what *jsDoSomething* is doing. It's an XAJAX function, and there's an option in that class that allows me to turn off the wait cursor. For some reason, I got caught up in thinking it was setInterval.